# How do I make it so Google spreadsheets can take in 3 arguments, and return back 1

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Right now in my Google Spreadsheet file, I have it so if a value goes negative, another cell will change to "Loss", and if it's positive, the cell will change the text to "Win"

```
= IF ( G58 < 0 , "Loss" , "Win" )
```

At the moment, it only takes in two arguments, whether the number is is negative or positive. But I want it to take in **another** argument, such as "blank", and if it sees that word, the output will resolve to: "NEUTRAL"

But if a negative or positive number is inputted, "WIN", or "LOSS" is still shown.[image]

Sorry if my question is worded weirdly, I'm not a programmer so I don't know the right vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

If inside If:

```
= IF ( G58 = "", "Neutral" , IF ( G58 < 0 , "Loss" , "Win" )  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with first checking the blank

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G58),"Neutral",IF(G58<0,"LOSS","WIN"))
```